# Как разобрать int число на цифры и преобразовать в int список

Tags: java

```
int num = 123;
```

**Надо вернуть:**

```
int[] numList{1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: берите остаток от деления на 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой линейный пример нужной вам функции:

```
   public static int[] intToArr(int i){
        List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        while (i >0){
            int mod = i % 10;
            ret.add(mod);
            i /= 10;
        }
        // создание массива нужной длинны
        int[] retI = new int[ret.size()];
        // заполнение массива со сменой порядка на нужный
        for(int j = retI.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            retI[retI.length - j - 1] = ret.get(j);
        return retI;
    }
```